# Problema con rutas amigables y php

Tags: php, php7, .htaccess

Tengo un problema con rutas amigables, cuando en la url no paso variables no carga correctamente la página `home` porque según no me reconoce una función pero cuando si paso variables en la url si carga correctamente todo.

Archivo **htaccess**:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-z\.]*)\/?([a-zA-Z]*)\/?([0-9]*)$ router.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3
```

Archivo **router.php**:

```
<?php
include_once("includes/config.php");
include_once("includes/clases/class.Contacto.php");

$entidad = $_GET["var1"];
$accion = $_GET["var2"];
$id = $_GET["var3"];

if(empty($entidad))
    $path = "home";
else
{
    if(strpos($entidad, ".") == false)
    {
        if(file_exists($entidad.".php"))
        {
           // Se accede al archivo php principal del sitio
        
           $path = $entidad;
        }
        else if(file_exists($entidad))
        {
           // Se accede a alguna subcarpeta del directorio principal del sitio
       
           $path = $entidad."/".$accion;       
        }   
    }
    else
    {
        // Se accede a alguna subcarpeta del directorio includes/acciones
        
        $entidades = explode(".", $entidad);
        $path = "includes/".$entidades[0]."/".$entidades[1]."/".$accion;
    }
}

include "./".$path.".php";
?>
```

Por ejemplo tengo esta url sin parámetros:

```
http://localhost/Agenda 1.2/
```

Como no hay parámetros en la url debe de cargar la página `home.php` y trata de cargarla pero muestra el siguiente error:

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
> base_url() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Agenda 1.2\home.php:7 Stack trace:
> #0 {main}   thrown in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Agenda 1.2\home.php** on line **7**

En cambio con esta url con parámetros no marca ningún error y carga todo correctamente:

```
http://localhost/Agenda 1.2/home
```

La función `base_url()` la tengo definida dentro del archivo `config.php`

¿Como puedo solucionar todo este problema?

Comment: Verifica qué sale si pones al principio un `var_dump($_GET);`. Si sale vacío posiblemente por ahí esté el problema. De ser así entonces cambia la captura de los parámetros GET a: `$entidad = isset($_GET["var1"]) ?? null;` y los mismo con `$accion` e `$id`.

Comment: @aeportugal no creo que tenga que ver con el php para mi el problema esta en el htaccess, porque cuando elimino la siguiente línea: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d toda url funciona muy bien pero cuando agrego esa línea empieza el problema